# Matrix multiplication function C++

Tags: c++, matrix

I seem to have an issue with my matrix multiplication function.

When I run the program I just get an n x n  matrix with all of the values the same, as some wired double value, e.g 21312e-2
Here is my function code:

```
void Multiply(int i, int j, double mat1[10][10], double mat2[10][10]) {


double mat3[10][10];
for (int r = 0; r < i; r++) {
    for (int c = 0; c < j; c++) {
        for (int in = 0; in < i; in++) {
            mat3[r][c] += mat1[r][in] * mat2[in][c];
        }
        cout << mat3[r][c] << "  ";
    }
    cout << "\n";
}
```

}

mat1 and mat 2 are read into the program in the main thread using the function read:

```
void read_matrix(int m, int n, double mat[10][10])
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i<m; ++i)
        for (j = 0; j<n; ++j)
            cin >> mat[i][j];
}
```

Edit:Main Code

```
int main()
{
    int i1, i2, j1, j2;
    double mat1[10][10], mat2[10][10], mat3[10][10];

    scanf_s("%d %d\n", &i1, &j1, mat1);


    read_matrix(i1, j1, mat1);

    scanf_s("%d %d\n", &i2, &j2, mat2);

    read_matrix(i2, j2, mat2);

    printf("%d x %d matrix\n", i1, j1);
    print_matrix(i1, j1, mat1);
    printf("\n%d x %d matrix\n", i2, j2);
    print_matrix(i2, j2, mat2);

    Multiply(i1, j2, mat1, mat2);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You haven't initialised each element of `mat3` to `0`.

Comment: What are the exact inputs, and what results do you get? Also, is the matrix square? If not, you'll need to actually convert the shape of `mat2`.

Comment: Stop torturing yourself and use a BLAS library. Much more performance, much less pain.

Comment: sorry the matrices are not square, Believe me if I could I would use a BLAS library but this is for class homework so I can't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to fill `mat3` with a zero value before adding to it.

Simplest way is to use:

```
double mat3[10][10] = {};
```

Comment: I still get huge double values that are not correct as the output, I have included my main code above.