# adding, subtracting, multiplying matrices in functions

Tags: c++, matrix

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

main()
{
int m, n, c, d, first[10][10], second[10][10], sum[10][10];

cout << "Enter the number of rows and columns of matrix ";
cin >> m >> n;
cout << "Enter the elements of first matrix\n";

for (  c = 0 ; c < m ; c++ )
  for ( d = 0 ; d < n ; d++ )
     cin >> first[c][d];

cout << "Enter the elements of second matrix\n";

for ( c = 0 ; c < m ;c++ )
  for ( d = 0 ; d < n ; d++ )
        cin >> second[c][d];

for ( c = 0 ; c < m ; c++ )
  for ( d = 0 ; d < n ; d++ )
     sum[c][d] = first[c][d] + second[c][d];

cout << "Sum of entered matrices:-\n";

for ( c = 0 ; c < m ; c++ )
{
  for ( d = 0 ; d < n ; d++ )
     cout << sum[c][d] << "\t";

  cout << endl;
}

return 0;
}
```

Hi guys so I found this source code online to add two matrices but I have a few questions to ask:
why was first[10][10], second[10][10], sum[10][10] declared to have a size 10 array?

Also, to make this a subtraction I simply just change the sign and few other things right?

How about multiplication? Any explanation on that? Thanks guys.

Comment: The arrays were declared with a size of 10 because that's what the author wanted. If you need more details than that you'll need to ask them.

Comment: _"why was first[10][10], second[10][10], sum[10][10] declared to have a size 10 array?"_ How should we know actually? 10x10 matrrix was sufficient for the questions requirements?

Comment: Where did you find it, what purpose did it serve? Regardless, I would suggest contacting the author for more information.

Comment: Multiplying matrices is a lot different than just changing the operator. Recommend learning how to do it with pencil and paper before trying it in code.

Comment: So if my matrix is 2 by 2, that means I can just declare it as a size 2 array right?

Comment: @kounliu Probably yes. Prefer any appropriate [standard container classes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) though!

Comment: What happens if I enter a size of 15, 20 for `m` and `n`?  Looks like buffer overflow.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please read the following page on how to ask a question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

> why was first[10][10], second[10][10], sum[10][10] declared to have a size 10 array?

The author of this program assumed maximum possible matrix size of 10 by 10.
Add the size of shrink it if you want.

> Also, to make this a subtraction I simply just change the sign and few other things right?

```
sum[c][d] = first[c][d] + second[c][d]; //Do what you want with this
```

> How about multiplication? Any explanation on that?

Try on pen and paper then translate to code.

Useful links:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strassen_algorithm
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873134.aspx
- [Matrix multiplication function C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28521765/matrix-multiplication-function-c)
- http://www.mindfreakerstuff.com/2013/08/program-for-multiplication-of-two-matrices-in-c/

Enjoy.

Comment: Side note - matrix multiplication is not commutative (A x B != B x A), so for a matrix multiply, there's a left matrix and a right matrix.